# PHP Ffmpeg Join Audio files and video

Tags: php, ffmpeg

I am trying to use the code bellow to join an audio file in the 6th second of my input video file and export all into one new video file but it doesnt run.

```
<?php
session_start();


$au = $_SESSION['mysound'];
$ffmpeg = "/usr/local/bin/ffmpeg";
$videofile = "video/sample.mp4";
$outputfile = "upload/outputvideo.mp4"; //This folder has full permissions


if (exec("-i $au -itsoffset 6 -i $videofile -acodec copy -vcodec copy $outputfile")){
echo "SUCCESS";
}else{
echo "FAILURE";
}

?>
```

Any help please?

Answer (score 1):

You can try this which this which sets the order of execution during the merge

```
ffmpeg -i $videofile -itsoffet 6 -i $au -acodec copy -vcodec copy $outputfile -map 0:0 -map 1:0
```

Comment: what -map 0:0 -map 1:0 does? Also where i must put the code for output file?